# Edittext arrows [Indesign Script]

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign, adobe-scriptui

I am trying to create an edittext (Indesign scripting) with arrow buttons next to it to edit the value, like this one:

[image: Result]

Now is just a simple code to draw a edittext.

```
var w = new Window('palette', "Palette");

var editText = w.add("edittext", undefined, "123");

w.show();
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is the list of Object Types that are exposed. I don't think this stepper edit box (aka Number Edit Box aka Nudge Edit Box) has been exposed via scripting as per your requirement.]

I tried to find the UI control in the Object Model browser via the name(s) (and others that might be similar) that InDesign C++ SDK has for this sort of control but ScriptUI does not have that.

IMO, you will have to go with an alternate approach i.e. create buttons with similar appearance, place them close to the edit-box and react on the notifications that these buttons will send on change.

Other than that, May I request that you post this to Adobe InDesign Developer forum as well. Please log a bug on Adobe InDesign as well for details as well. That should get you the right approach if there is any as they also might be using internally.